Can ExternalTaskSensor handle multiple task_ids?
This question is an addendum to Can I use airflow tags to determine if all DAGs with a certain tag has finished running?
My challenge now is that rather than having a dependency on one task_id, I have multiple task_ids that I would like to wait to finish running before I run my new task.
Is this possible?
I have all the task_ids in a list.
